# How to capture an event from a UI (web) when I don't have access to the source code

Tags: c#, email, events, version-control, ssjs

So, here's the use case.  I work for Salesforce Marketing Cloud as a technology architect.  We have a very robust "Marketing Cloud" app which I don't do any development on.  I don't have access to source code/etc.  I do have access to the application though, as a user.

Quick 2 sentence overview of the application: big companies like "Company A" utilize our software to be able to send billions of emails (promotional and transactional) to their customers.  So, say you get an email from "Company A" telling you of all the great products they offer - that email is sent from our system.

So, the use case: the Marketing Cloud application, for simplicity's sake, is able to create an email from HTML.  Basically, the user (myself) can copy/paste HTML into the huge text field, and click Save, and the email code is saved into the back end (SQL Server table).  This application does not have any kind of source control to manage the different versions of the "email" that the user decides to create/change/modify.

Now, I have access to develop a customized "whatever" via C#/SSJS that has access to all of the elements in the database that the application writes to.  So, if I wanted to grab the latest version of an "email" saved by a user, I can simply write a SQL query to grab this content.

Here's my goal: To create a very simple version control system without getting into the source code of the application.  Ambitious, I know.  I have all the different pieces of this mapped out in a document, but the one obstacle I'm running into is "how can I capture the 'save' event for when a user clicks 'save' and saves an email"?  I believe this is a client side event, but I'm not 100% sure.  My initial thought is to write a browser extension, but not knowing exactly what browser extensions have the capability of doing, I'm not sure if this is a good route to take.  How can I capture an event from a UI from a web based application when I don't have access to the source code?

Comment: I would think it would be easier to add a table to hold the original html version and any information needed to track it, then add an UPDATE trigger to the current table.

Comment: Have you tried [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)?

Comment: I have not, I'll check it out!